# How to get members of a discord guild(discord.py)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-3.8

I know some of the answers for this one would be:

```
for member in guild.members:
    id = member.id
    #do stuff here
```

But no, that doesn't work for me, I already tried that and it only has the bot itself inside of the list of members, though it does show the actual member count(but I'm not sure if that's useful in any way). So I'm asking if there is another way to do this.

Comment: Please check the docs on intents to enable in your bot code and in the developer portal - [A Primer to Gateway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#a-primer-to-gateway-intents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Discord intents system broke a lot of things, so you need to make sure `discord.py` is updated and you instantiate your client with all intents:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Comment: I think you actually have to enable it in the web dashboard. `Guild Members` is a privileged intent.